# Get lower case letters from oracle 10g columns

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

The following query shows validating user login credentials with frist name and password from oracle 10g database.

In my database first name contains Upper case and Lower case, but from front end side i always get lower case letters.

```
SELECT customer_name, CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM customer
 WHERE     first_name = '"+customer.getFirstname()+"'
       AND password = '"+customer.getPassword()+"'
```

I want to check with db with lower case only. Any possible way to do with oracle query..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In query itself you can do.

For Lower

```
lower(first_name)
```

For Upper

```
upper(first_name)
```

Here you can change your query as shown below.

```
SELECT customer_name, CUSTOMER_ID from customer where lower(first_name)='"+customer.getFirstname()+"' AND password='"+customer.getPassword()+"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with lowercase only name, but not a password! The password should contain lowercase and uppercase letters, and probably special symbols to allow better protection.

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_id
  FROM customer
 WHERE     lower(first_name) = lower('"+customer.getFirstname()+"')
       AND password = '"+customer.getPassword()+"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_id
  FROM customer
 WHERE     lower(first_name) = lower('"+customer.getFirstname()+"')
       AND lower(password) = lower('"+customer.getPassword()+"')
```

Comment: Here customer.getFirstname() will always lower case only, so no need to use lower('"+customer.getFirstname()+"')

Comment: @vinod_vh Yes, you are right, however what if logic gets changed at a later stage!